# Use Google instead of Bing with Windows 10 search

Tags: windows-10

I want to use Google Chrome and Google search instead of Bing when I search in Windows 10.

Google Chrome is launched when I click on web, but it's Bing search. (My default search engine on Google and Edge is http://www.google.com)

[image: Screenshot]

I haven't found how to configure that.

Someone can help me ?

Comment: https://medium.com/requestly-docs/use-your-preferred-search-engine-31089cb2a9c9 - Here is an article which explains how you can use [Requestly Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa?hl=en)  to use your preferred search engine without actually modifying any setting inside the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to change the default in Cortana itself but you can redirect it in Chrome. You said that it opens the results in the Chrome browser but it used Bing search right?

There's a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrometana/kaicbfmipfpfpjmlbpejaoaflfdnabnc) now that will [redirect Bing to Google, DuckDuckGo, or Yahoo](http://www.ibtimes.com/how-change-cortanas-bing-default-search-engine-google-using-chrometana-2032349), whichever you prefer. More information on that in the second link.

Comment: Perfect, it's work !. Thanks @MC10.

Comment: Didn't notice you edited your comment with further information and links. Now I look like a buffoon :)

Comment: I what? My answer was always posted like this but yours is good too.

Comment: Microsoft stopped using the default browser for Cortana since the Anniversary update, so this no longer works directly.

Answer (score 3):

## Use **[EdgeAndBingDeflector](https://github.com/radialapps/EdgeAndBingDeflector)**

This tiny programs diverts all your Cortana searches to your default browser and converts them (optionally) to Google or DuckDuckGo.

You can directly download it [here](https://github.com/radialapps/EdgeAndBingDeflector/releases)

Tested on the newest Creator's Update

(P.S. I've forked this project from the original project "EdgeDeflector" and modified to divert Bing to other search engines)

Comment: Rather than posting with the exact same content on two questions you should be trying to tailor your answers to the question at hand. If that cannot be done because the questions are ostensibly identical then you should be doing what you have done and flagging to be closed as a duplicate. Additionally we require that all recommendations for your own products or solutions are *fully* disclosed.  See "Avoid overt self promotion" in https://superuser.com/help/behavior

Comment: @Mokubai, actually I had already answered this question when I found the other one. Then I posted my answer to the other one and marked this one as duplicate, as I felt the other was a bit broader and better. I've edited the answer to include that I've coded this partially, but I didn't do that earlier since I've actually done little; most of the code was forked from EdgeDeflector.

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. Use Google Chrome <sup>(instead of Edge)</sup>

Per [How to Make Cortana Search with Google and Chrome Instead of Bing and Edge](https://www.howtogeek.com/226638/make-the-windows-10-start-menu-and-cortana-search-google-instead-of-bing/), you can download the Original [**EdgeDeflector**](https://github.com/da2x/EdgeDeflector/releases/tag/v1.1.3.0) (use Instead of PulseJet's fork above).  Next time you search, select EdgeDeflector as the default app.

[image]

Cortana / Start Menu Search redirects links by using the protocol `URL:microsoft-edge`. 
 **EdgeDeflector** works by also registering that protocol and allowing you to select the default browser to handle the web request

[image]

#### 2. Use Google Search <sup>(instead of Bing)</sup>

The second problem is when chrome opens, the URL is still pointed to a bing search

Next, you can use [**Requestly**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa?hl=en) chrome extension to redirect urls.  While you can redirect all URLs against Bing, that will also prevent you from any searches you make yourself.  Cortana adds some extra query params (`form=WNSGPH`) and we can opt to redirect only when those are present and forward along the search terms.

So redirect this request based on [this regex](https://regexr.com/45bch):

```
/https:\/\/www\.bing\.com\/search\?q=(.*)&form=WNSGPH.*/
```

To this URL:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=$1
```

Comment: Great answer @KyleMit. A couple of weeks, I made this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHzjyFdMlZs to redirect bing query to google and show google results in chrome when default search engine is bing in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The start search in Windows 10 uses the default search engine defined in the Microsoft Edge browser. By default, of course, this is Bing.

to change to DuckDuckGo:

- Launch the Microsoft Edge browser
- Go to https://duckduckgo.com/
- Click the ... icon at the top right
- Click Settings
- Scroll down and click "View advanced settings"
- Under "Search in the address bar with" select "Add New"
- Select "DuckDuckGo" and click "Add as default"

Confirm that it's all working by doing a search in the Edge browser and making sure the results go to DuckDuckGo.

The Start Search should now start using the same. Note you might have to restart your machine for the Start Search to realise the change.

Comment: Does this method require that Edge is the default browser? I'm currently using Chrome as my default.

Comment: Nope, wheter or not Edge the default browser, its settings can be modified.

Answer (score 0):

### Changing default search engine in Windows 10

There have been only workarounds providing this functionality at this time. One of the said workarounds below-

1. Download Google Chrome extension [Bing2Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bing2google/mgoehlfmhfafaiepckjikpphoklijedl?hl=en) or [Chrometana](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrometana/kaicbfmipfpfpjmlbpejaoaflfdnabnc)
2. Done! All searches from Bing are re-directed to Google, even ones done at their web page manually.

Comment: You need to first deflect Cortana to Chrome as of today ;)

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, it is not possible to do this without a *third-party extension*. If you want to use Google Chrome with Cortana, you'll have to install the Chrome extension, *Chrometana*.

If you are a Firefox user, it is apparently possible to use whatever search engine you would like, if you have Firefox as your default browser. I tried this yesterday, but I had no luck with it. Maybe I was doing something wrong.

You can check out the article [here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2969381/browsers/firefox-sticks-it-to-microsoft-redirects-cortana-searches-in-windows-10.html).